# How to create postgres table with airflow

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've written the below DAG and the idea is to create and insert records into a Postgres database table, I've set my connection successfully through the Airflow UI an used the correct database credential.

I've both my airflow and Postgres running on docker, the DAG ran successfully multiple times but the table doesn't get created in the database.

Is there any settings or something I need to do more?

Below is a copy of my dag:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    "owner" : "FarsH",
    "email" : 'farshrandom@gmail.com',
    "email_on_retry" : False,
    "email_on_failure" : False,
    "retries" : 2,
    "retry_delay" : timedelta(minutes=5)
    }

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'db_cnctn_trial',
    description = 'Trying to connect postgres',
    start_date = datetime(2024, 1, 24, 18, 30),
    schedule_interval = '@daily', #We can use cron guru like '0 0 * * *'
    default_args = default_args,
    #catch_up = True
    )

task_1 = PostgresOperator(
    dag =  dag,
    task_id = 'create_a_pg_table',
    #task_description = 'creating a postgres table',
    postgres_conn_id = 'pg_ps_airflow',
    sql = '''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dag_trial (
    SN SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    REPORT_DATE DATE,
    USER_ID VARCHAR(30))
    ''')

task_2 = PostgresOperator(
    dag =  dag,
    task_id = 'data_insertion_n',
    #task_description = 'inserting records into a postgres table',
    postgres_conn_id = 'pg_ps_airflow',
    sql = '''
    INSERT INTO dag_trial (REPORT_DATE, USER_ID)
    VALUES ('2023-10-12', 'NG2022')
    '''
    )

task_1 >> task_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your DAG to include some logging statements to print information during the DAG execution. For example, you can add print statements or use the Python logging module to log information that might help you diagnose the issue.

This way u can debug your issue.

```
import logging

## Add the following lines before or after task_1 and task_2

logging.info(f'Creating table: {task_1.sql}')
logging.info(f'Inserting data: {task_2.sql}')
```

Comment: I can't past all of the log files, but it reads success and below is the last part of it

[2024-01-27, 08:21:40 WAT] {taskinstance.py:1350} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=db_cnctn_trial, task_id=create_a_pg_table, execution_date=20240127T072125, start_date=20240127T072138, end_date=20240127T072140
[2024-01-27, 08:21:41 WAT] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2024-01-27, 08:21:41 WAT] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check